# Java Akka Scheduling API throwing MissingMethodException

Tags: java, groovy, akka, scheduling

Java 8 (well, Groovy) using Akka `com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.5.4` here. I'm trying to create an actor (`AppMaster`) that creates/owns/manages another actor (`StateChecker`) and is scheduled to send this `StateChecker` a `CheckState` message every 4 seconds:

```
class CheckState {}

class StateChecker extends AbstractActor {
  // For this question, it really doesn't matter what this actor does
}

class AppMaster extends AbstractActor {
    ActorRef stateChecker

    @Override
    Receive createReceive() {
      receiveBuilder()
            .match(Init, { message ->
              stateChecker = context.actorOf(Props.create(StateChecker, "yes", 20), "state-checker")

              FiniteDuration startDur = Duration.Zero()

              FiniteDuration freqDur = Duration.create(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
              CheckState checkState = new CheckState()
              ExecutionContextExecutor executor = context.system().dispatcher()

              context.system().scheduler().schedule(startDur, freqDur, stateChecker, checkState,
                executor)
            })
        .build()
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.schedule() is applicable for argument types: (scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration, scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration, akka.actor.LocalActorRef, com.me.myapp.messages.CheckState, akka.dispatch.Dispatcher) values: [0 days, 4000 milliseconds, Actor[akka://myapp/user/myapp-master/o1-keeper#-1837899613], ...]
Possible solutions: schedule(scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration, scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration, java.lang.Runnable, scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext), schedule(scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration, scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration, scala.Function0, scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext), schedule(scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration, scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration, akka.actor.ActorRef, java.lang.Object, scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext, akka.actor.ActorRef)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
```

I added in log statements and the exception is being thrown during the scheduling:

```
context.system().scheduler().schedule(startDur, freqDur, stateChecker, checkState,
  executor)
```

Any idea what I need to do to fix this? Since this is an issue I'm having with Akka's Java API, I *do* need the answer to be via the Java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the arguments that you're passing to the `schedule()` method match none of the overloaded versions of that method. You can see the signatures of the overloaded versions of `schedule()` in the [JavaDoc](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5.4/akka/actor/Scheduler.html).

The version that you're trying to use is the following [method](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5.4/akka/actor/Scheduler.html#schedule-scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration-scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration-akka.actor.ActorRef-java.lang.Object-scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext-akka.actor.ActorRef-):

```
Cancellable schedule(scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration initialDelay,
                     scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration interval,
                     ActorRef receiver,
                     java.lang.Object message,
                     scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext executor,
                     ActorRef sender)
```

You're missing the last parameter, which is an `ActorRef` that is designated as the sender of the scheduled message. If `StateChecker` doesn't care who sends it the `CheckState` message, then the easiest fix is to pass in `null` as this last parameter:

```
context.system()
       .scheduler()
       .schedule(startDur, freqDur, stateChecker, checkState, executor, null)
                                                                     // ^
```

Comment: you should prefer `Actor.noSender()` to `null`